# Migrating sonar rules from sonarqube 4.4 to 4.5.4LTS

Tags: sonarqube

While migrating from sonarqube 4.4 to 4.5.4 is there a way to migrate all the rules in **sonar way** and **sonar way with findbugs** quality profiles?

I noticed that the total number of rules have decreased in the latter version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice that the total number of rules have decreased, this is probably because:

- either you haven't reinstalled all your previous plugins
- or the some plugins have removed some rules which are therefore no more compatible. (and those rules can't be "migrated")

Comment: I'm using sonar bundled rulesets only.
So are you suggesting that I move the sonar plugin jars from 4.4 to 4.5.4?

Comment: The SonarQube Java plugin is independent from SonarQube itself. They don't follow the same version lifecycle.

Comment: I checked the compatibility matrix and found sonar 4.4 supports 2.5.1 and sonar 4.5.4 supports 3.3 version of java plugin.
I hope moving 2.5.1 to 4.5.4 will cause issues. Anyway I'll give that a try and get back ;)

Comment: I upgraded plugin versions according to the compatibility matrix. Everything looks fine now.

I have an older instance that is so slow. Can you help me with the same?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290413/sonar-analysis-takes-long-time)