# Sonar analysis takes long time

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

My sonar analysis takes a long time to complete. Initially it took around 20-30 mins. Later it increased to 1hr+. Now after 5 months it takes whole 5 hours. 
Can someone suggest the reason and how to rectify the same.

I use sonarqube 4.4 with postgresql 9.3 db. The sonar db takes up almost 40G of space.

If you check my log below you will notice that most of the time is spent on IndexProjectPostJob.

```
08:53:47.437 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
08:53:48.687 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
12:56:24.924 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
12:56:26.601 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2015-06-10 and 2015-07-07
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of Junit/Integration tests that run each time sonar is analyzing your code it can take a long time before it is finished.

If this is the case , maybe you should move (part) of your tests (for example the once that use the db) to a separate sonar project, which you'll only run once in a while. And run only your small and real unit tests.

Comment: No i don't execute any junit tests with sonar. Its pure sonar analysis. If you see the log you will notice that job takes up lot of time executing db indexing.

Comment: Ok, other question. Which kind of sonar analysis are you doing?

http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/

if you use analysis you might try one of the others

Comment: I'm doing **analysis**, hence the DB indexing.
There is no issue in preview mode as I'm not persisting anything to DB.

Comment: so, why do you want to use "analysinng" every time?

Comment: I do preview analysis along with my build and a nightly quality analysis.
In your opinion how do I do it ?
Btw we are still not talking about solution to the issue

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it might take sonarQube so long to do his analysis. what (DB) changes has there been during those 5 mnonth period.

Comment: Below is my table sizes over the period. I believe the query takes long time to read data from project measures
`"public.project_measures";"19 GB"
"public.snapshot_data";"8281 MB"
"public.snapshot_sources";"6856 MB"
"public.snapshots";"2214 MB"
"public.dependencies";"1831 MB"
"public.issues";"816 MB"
"public.resource_index";"106 MB"
"public.notifications";"64 MB"
"public.semaphores";"56 MB"
"public.issue_changes";"22 MB"
"public.projects";"19 MB"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82891/discussion-between-gautam-jose-and-bgvv1983).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a lot of snapshots. Would it be possible to delete some.
Which version of SonarQube do you use ?

Regards.

Comment: I use sonarqube 4.4 and yes I do have a lot of snapshots.
I use the default database cleaner settings. 
If  the default settings is not ideal for big projects, can you kindly suggest me a feasible db cleaner settings?

Comment: I had 40+ snapshots for the project. I deleted a few, still no difference. 
Also I need to keep snapshots of at least 3 weeks.

Comment: No, I don't have any suggestion, except: 1. Try to maintain the number of snapshots lower, you could have 1 per week after 2 week, 1 per month after 1 month, for example. But I understand that it depends of your quality process. 2. Do some optimization at DB level. I don't know Postgress, but on Oracle, you have to rebuild the indexes periodically and especially if DB has been growing a lot. Good luck.